# Connecting veth directly to physical interface

Tags: linux, docker, networking, containers

I was wondering is it possible to create a **veth** interface and connect it directly to physical interface of NIC? I see most of the online solutions using bridges, however I am curious if it would be possible to bypass them for simple connection.

These are the some commands I tried to achieve this, but received error:

```
sudo ip link add veth1 type veth

sudo ip link set veth1 master ens3f0np0
```

(ens3f0np0 being physical interface)

Error I received after second command was: **RTNETLINK answers: Operation not supported**

Comment: This question would more suitable at https://unix.stackexchange.com. A `veth` interface is an interface pair; you can't "attach" it to another interface. You can add one of the pair to a bridge and put your physical interface on the same bridge. Also take a look at the [macvlan network](https://docs.docker.com/network/macvlan/) documentation for another option for attach a container to a physical interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that MACVLAN would be solution needed for this scenario.

Following is a helpful link:
[Red Hat MACVLAN explanation](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2018/10/22/introduction-to-linux-interfaces-for-virtual-networking#macvlan)